# Issue with window.close and chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-ios

I'm trying to close a child window with JavaScript, and in Firefox everything works fine but in Chrome the window doesn't close.

Here is what I'm using

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed)
        window.opener.location = "http://www.website.com"
    window.close();
});
```

I tried a suggestion on [google](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=23c03746e3aa03f9&hl=en), but to no avail.

Anyone having a similar issue or know of a work-around?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I know this question is old, but I ran into the same problem. This worked for me:

```
window.open('', '_self', ''); //bug fix
window.close();
```

Comment: @Long I think because the bug fix crashed with first window.open() so it should be delayed.
@Warren Thanks.

Comment: How future-proof is this solution? Does anyone know why this works? I thought the general rule was that you could not close a window that was not opened with JavaScript.

Comment: @WalterStabosz If you directly use window.close() then it will not work because only tab that opened from javascript are allowed to close. So we open some blank url in same window and then try to close it via javascript and it works!!

Comment: I can't get this to work; I've opened the child window using LyteBox, and I can "post back" to the main window using parent.document, but then it just ignores the window.close - which is odd, as the child window was opened using JavasScript in the first place.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work anymore, unless I serve the page locally.

Answer (score 10):

If previously you open some other window by `window.open()`

**This don't work:**

```
window.open(...)
window.open('', '_self', '');
window.close();
```

**But work:**

```
window.open(...);
setTimeout(function(){
    window.open('', '_self', '');
    window.close();
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should also work:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    window.close();
},50);
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me - it doesn't error, it just does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's working in Chrome Kiosk ( Fullscreen ) mode. Tried successfully.

Answer (score 1):

top.window.close() works for me. Tested on IE, FF, Chrome, Safari and Opera.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
var win = window.open("about:blank", "_self");
win.close();
```