# in a pop up after using window.location to redirect, window.close becomes undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, redirect, popup

Here is what is happening...

My website redirects to Third Party Website which uses `window.location` to redirect back to my website. All this is happenining inside a pop up window.

The issue i am facing is in Chrome, after the redirect `window.close` is `undefined` along with some other attributes like `window.opener` 
Any idea how can I close this window ?

Don't have much control over how redirection is happening as its a third party  website.

I changed `window.location` in one of my pages to redirect to another page and in that page this issue was reproducible.

EDIT:

The issue was not `window.location` redirection but something else ... Trying to debug it further, have found a solution though and answered in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first answer in this question worked:
[Issue with window.close and chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032640/problem-with-window-close-and-chrome)

```
window.open('','_self', '');
window.close();
```

This works... the only reasong that i can think of is, on calling `window.open` window object is reinitialized in the pop up and hence `window.close()` does not return `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Once the open window navigates to a domain that is not the same as the parent, you no longer have access to the window from the parent.

To workaround this you can have a page on your site that just contains an `iframe` with the `src` attribute set to the appropriate 3rd party website url.

Comment: I am not trying to access from the parent but calling window.close inside the pop up itself.