# window.close(); javascript code not working with chrome

Tags: javascript, css, html, mootools

I have an image javascript button that it`s not working on chrome ,

would you please helping me 
Thanks in advance!

here is the code:

I just hide the pop up:

**Edit :**

for closing I`m using this function just hide it

```
function hideBulle() {
    $("bullepopup").style.display="none";
    hideoverlay();
}
```

and here is the code for creating one box and this button

```
  function showBulle(obj) {
    showoverlay();
    coo =   $("content").getPosition();
    $("bullepopup").style.width = "555px";
    $("bullepopup").style.height = "555px";
    $("bullepopup").position({x: (coo.x+((650-555)/2)), y: (coo.y+(440-250)/2)});
    $("bullepopup").style.display="";
    $("bullepopup").set('html','');
    new Element('img',{src:'images/br588.gif',styles: {float:'right',cursor:'pointer'},
                            events: {
                                click: function(){
                                hideBulle();
                                }
                            }
                        }).inject($('bullepopup'));

    new Element('br').inject($('bullepopup'));

    new Element('div',{html:obj.get('html')}).inject($('bullepopup'));
}
function hideBulle() {
    $("bullepopup").style.display="none";
    hideoverlay();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what library are you using? That should be tagged

Comment: what is the `Element` function? is that native javascript? what is `inject`?

Comment: @JuanMendes I`m using /mootools-more-1.4.0.1.js that I put it already

Comment: @jbabey yes I create new element with new Element and with inject I will put it inside element

Comment: Do you want to change url of current window? As window.open('','_self',''); will make changes in own window because of self.

Comment: @Shusl since I will load the popup, and this button is in this popup and just hide the pop up , check my edit please

Comment: What about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032640/problem-with-window-close-and-chrome

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check your css with chrome developer tool , you should have some frame in your button

remove  or change it

you can try this code also

```
window.open('', '_self', ''); //bug fix
window.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

top.window.close() works for me. Tested on IE, FF, Chrome, Safari and Opera.