# Java Socket HTML response

Tags: java, html, http, sockets

I'm trying to get a Java socket to send a simple HTML response to a browser.

Here's my Java code:

```
    Socket socket = server.accept();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    String s;
    // this is a test code which just reads in everything the requester sends
    while ((s = in.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
        if (s.isEmpty())
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    // send the response to close the tab/window
    String response = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.close();</script>";

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
    out.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    out.println("Content-Type: text/html");
    out.println("Content-Length: " + response.length());
    out.println();
    out.println(response);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    socket.close();
```

`server` is a ServerSocket set to automatically pick an open port to use.

The idea is any webpage redirected to `http:\\localhost:port` (where `port` is the port `server` is listening to) is closed automatically.

When this code gets run, my browser receives the response and I've verified that it receives all the information that I'm sending.

However, the window/tab isn't closing, and I can't even close the tab by manually issuing a `window.close();` command into the Javascript console for my browser.

What am I missing here? I know that an html page with the given content should automatically close the window/tab, so why isn't this working? I'm testing this on Google Chrome.

I've tried a more complete html webpage, but still no luck.

Here's what the browser is reporting as the page source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">window.close();</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens when you correct `Context-Type` to `Content-Type`?

Comment: If `window.close()` does not work through the console, the server is not to blame. Try adding proper `doctype` and the `<html><head>` tags anyways.

Comment: `window.close()` from the console works for me. Try wrapping in `<html><head>`

Comment: Try self.close().  Also, I saw this thread: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/GjsCrvPYGlA.  I'm using IE, but window.close() did not work for me in the browser.  However, I try self.close() and it worked.

Comment: still no luck for me with a more valid html page, or trying to use self.close()

Comment: It seems `window.close()` doesn't work from the local machine

Comment: I can't call `window.close()` (returns without effect) in a page opened through the `file://` protocol, even from the console

Comment: This might explain window.close issues:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032640/problem-with-window-close-and-chrome.  I changed to <script type=\"text/javascript\">window.open('', '_self', '');window.close();</script> and this works.

Comment: Ahh, the answer to that question fixed my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize the comments:

The root issue is actually the one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032640/problem-with-window-close-and-chrome), where window.close() won't close the current window/tab.

I looked up the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.close) and found this:

> When this method is called, the referenced window is closed.
>
> This method is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened by a script using the window.open method. If the window was not opened by a script, the following error appears in the JavaScript Console: Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.

Apparently Google Chrome wasn't considering the current window to be opened by the script. I also tried this in Firefox which exhibits the same behavior.

To get around this, I must first open the current window using a script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.open('', '_self', '');
    window.close();
</script>
```