# window.close event in javascript not working in IE,chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the below code I am using `onbeforeunload` event.  This event fires when tab or browser is closed.  This code is working fine in Firefox but this event also fires in IE9 but in another system have IE compatibility versions IE8,9 and 10.  In that compatibility mode 8,9,10.  This event is not firing at all.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    window.onbeforeunload = WindowCloseHanlder;
    function WindowCloseHanlder()
    {
        window.alert('My Window is reloading');
    }
</script>
```

I had used `onbeforeunload` event which calls the function `windowclosehandler`.  When I call this function I am just giving one alert to check whether that event fires or not.

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032640/problem-with-window-close-and-chrome

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    window.onbeforeunload = WindowCloseHanlder;
    function WindowCloseHanlder()
    {
       alert('My Window is reloading');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: check this.... whether this will work or not. Some times this minor change is the main reason for not getting the result.

Comment: @Rony Thanx I was miss this

Comment: i had changed IE settings its working now but its not working in chrome